# Email not being sent after submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mail-form

I'm trying to finish an application form that gets emailed to an employer once the submit button is hit. I had it working a few days ago, but I made so many little changes to my code that now the form won't send. I can send an email from inside the console though. I've looked at so many different posts and tutorials but I can't figure it out.

**Controller**

```
    def new
       @form = Form.new
    end 

    def create
        @form = Form.new(params)
      if @form.deliver
        redirect_to careers_path, :notice => 'Thank you for applying.'
      else
        redirect_to new_form_path, :notice => 'Message could not be sent. Please try again.'
      end
   end
```

**Model**

```
class Form < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :salary, :validate => true
  attribute :location, :validate => true
  attribute :message, :validate => true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "Applicant",
      :to => "123@email.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for new_form_path, method: :post do |f| %>
      <div>
          <%= f.label :name %><br/>
          <%= f.text_field  :name, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area" %></br>
          </br>
          <%= f.label :email %><br/>
          <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area" %></br>
          </br>
          <%= f.label :location %><br/>
          <%= f.text_field :location, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area" %></br>
          </br>
          <%= f.label :salary %><br/>
          <%= f.text_field :salary, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area" %></br>
          </br>
        <%= f.label :message %><br/>
        <%= f.text_area :message, rows: 8, cols: 40, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area",
                          placeholder: "Inlcude extra details"%></br>

        <br/>
        <div align="center">
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors= true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_EMAIL"],
    password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

**routes**

```
resources :forms, only: [:new, :create]
    post '/forms/new', to: 'forms#create'
```

**Log**

```
Started POST "/forms/new" for ::1 at 2020-04-10 18:46:10 -0700
Processing by FormsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hwQ5eKNZptSK0w8E4C+UdvS+7TuUg5esYXyp8FMt/008s+RAiRrt/0oXpKVwGbJ5JbOpjtqbAqxTO/aoDWXZMA==", "/forms/new"=>{"name"=>"person", "email"=>"123@email.com", "location"=>"somewhere", "salary"=>"$$$", "message"=>"testing"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/forms/new
Name can't be blank
Email can't be blank
Salary can't be blank
Location can't be blank
Message can't be blank
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/forms/new" for ::1 at 2020-04-10 18:46:10 -0700
Processing by FormsController#new as HTML
  Rendering forms/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered forms/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 197ms (Views: 194.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: I don't get an explicit error. I get the message of ''Message could not be sent. Please try again.'' from the else statement in the forms controller

Comment: I'm still pretty new to rails. I added @form.errors into the else statement but I didn't see anything different once I submitted the form.

Comment: Ok so I just ran that and in my new logs this stood out "#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fa678017298>"

Comment: That gave me more info. I'll update the log above...

Comment: Show the controller code handling request and what you get in params from the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that nothing in the @form object is set.

According to the log, the parameters are being passed in...

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token", 
"/forms/new"=>{"name"=>"person", "email"=>"123@email.com",
"location"=>"somewhere", "salary"=>"$$$", "message"=>"testing"}, 
"commit"=>"Submit"}
```

but not being set into the object. So, my bet is these two lines

```
@form = Form.new(params[:form])
@form.request = request
```

Should be replaced by

```
@form = Form.new(params)
```

That should set all the properties on the @form object.

Comment: I changed those lines of code in the controller but I'm still getting the same output in the logs. I'll keep working with it today and hopefully figure it out. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?  Are you using strong parameters?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm using rails 5.2.3, and I don't think I'm using strong parameters

Comment: I finally got it working! I just needed to add a method in my controller permitting the parameters. So simple yet such a puzzle. Thank you for your help figuring it out!